# Checking a HTML element's class

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
$('pre').each(function(index) {
    var c = $(this).attr("class");
    if (!c) {
        return true;
    }
    // Match only Javascript code snippets
    if (!c.match(/brush: js; class-name: 'jsbox'/)) {
        return true;
    }
    var code = $(this).text();
    $(this).after($("<button>Run example</button>").click(function() {
        run(code);
    }));
```

I noticed if I didn't have `if (!c) {` then the loop could abrubtly halt if it found a `<pre>` element without a class.

I wonder how to write this more succinctly. I'm also wondering about my matching options, since I've noticed different ways people match / compare strings in Javascript and I wondered what was "de rigueur".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like whatever library you're using is generating properties and sticking them inside the `class` attribute, which I've never seen before and seems questionable (why can't they be attributes on the element?). Because they look generated, could you maybe end up with something like this:

```
<pre class="class-name: 'jsbox'; brush: js">
```

or this:

```
<pre class="brush: js; [another property]; class-name: 'jsbox'">
```

If so, then you may want to only look for one property (like `brush: js`) to determine if you're looking at a JS code snippet.

It's fine to use `String.match()` for finding a substring but realize that `String.indexOf()` is preferable if you have no need for regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4757501/1100355

So you would end up with something like this:

```
var c = $(this).attr("class");
if (!c || c.indexOf('brush: js') < 0) {
  return true;
}

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var code = $(this).text();
```

to

```
var code = $(this).val();
```

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that I want to compress the '!c' lines.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/mfJMb/

```
$('pre').each(function(){
  var $t = $(this);

  // Match only Javascript code snippets
  if( ( $t.attr("class") || '') .match(/brush: js; class-name: 'jsbox'/) ){
    $t.after($("<button>Run example</button>").click(function(){
        alert( $t.text() );
    }));
  }
});
```

Comment: I like this answer, but you should have copied in the "TidyUp" version since I find the `$t` variable name, unconventional.